# counting and numbering in a select statement in Access SQL

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

Could you please help me figuring out how to accomplish the following.

I have a table containing the number of products available between one date and another as per below:

**TABLE MyProducts**

```
DateProduct  ProductId   Quantity   Price  
26/02/2016      7          2        100
27/02/2016      7          3        100
28/02/2016      7          4        100
```

I have created a form where users need to select a date range and the number of products they are looking for (in my example, the number of products is going to be 1).

In this example, let's say that a user makes the following selection:

```
SELECT SUM(MyProducts.Price) As TotalPrice
FROM MyProducts WHERE MyProducts.DateProduct 
Between #2/26/2016# And #2/29/2016#-1 AND MyProducts.Quantity>=1
```

Now the user can see the total amount that 1 product costs: 300

For this date range, however, I want to allow users to select from a combobox also the number of products that they can still buy: if you give a look at the Quantity for this date rate, a user can only buy a maximum of 2 products because 2 is the lowest quantity available is in common for all the dates listed in the query.

**First question:**  how can I feed the combobox with a "1 to 2" list (in this case) considering that 2 is lowest quantity available in common for all the dates queried by this user?

**Second question:** how can I manage the products that a user has purchased.
Let's say that a user has purchased 1 product  within this date range and a second user has purchased for the very same date range the same quantity too (which is 1) for a total of 2 products purchased already in this date range. How can I see that for this date rate and giving this case the number of products actually available are:

```
DateProduct  ProductId   Quantity   Price  
    26/02/2016      7          0        100
    27/02/2016      7          1        100
    28/02/2016      7          2        100
```

Thank you in advance and please let me know should you need further information.

Comment: For the first question use `min()`. The second is not possible to understand without a clearer picture of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I tried to follow your suggestion but unfortunately this doesnt take me to what I was asking for: "SELECT MIN(MyProducts.Quantity) As myQuantity FROM MyProducts" returns 2 and this is correct. However, what's missing here is how to put in a combox a list of numbers  based on the min() select statement above, that is 1 and 2. As for the second question: users select a date range and the numbers of product they want to purchase and I show them how many products are still available in that date range like in a booking engine. Please clarify what is not clear in my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table with an integer field counting from 1 to whatever max qty you could expect. Then create a query that will only return rows from your new table up to the min() qty in the MyProducts table. Use that query as the control source of your combobox.

EDIT: You will actually need two queries. The first should be:

```
SELECT Min(MyProducts.Quantity) AS MinQty FROM MyProducts;
```

which I called "qryMinimumProductQty". I create the table called "Numbering" with a single integer field called "Sequence". The second query:

```
SELECT Numbering.Sequence FROM Numbering, qryMinimumProductQty WHERE Numbering.Sequence<=qryMinimumProductQty.MinQty;
```

AFAIK there is no Access function/feature that will fill in a series of numbers in a combobox control source. You have to build the control source yourself. (Anyone with more VBA experience might have a solution to solve this, but I do not.)

It makes me ache thinking of an entire table with a single integer column only being used for a combobox though. A simpler approach to the combobox would just to show the qty available in a control on your form, give an unbound text box for the user to enter their order qty, and add a validation rule to stop the order and notify them if they have chosen a number greater than the qty on hand. (Just a thought)

As for your second question, I don't really understand what you're looking for either. It sounds like there may be another table of purchases? It should be a simple query to relate MyProducts to Purchases and take the difference between your MyProducts!qty and the Purchases!qty. If you don't have a table to store Purchases, it might be warranted based on my cursory understanding of your system.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks a lot for your explanation and inputs. I would now focus on the 1st question. How would you suggest to implement the select statement  that will only return rows of the new table up to the min() qty in the MyProducts table? Thank you in advance